# How to configure Hibernate logging?

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, logging

The sample application I am developing keeps writing all the Hibernate queries to Tomcat console. I mean if you start Tomcat on Windows, you will have a small applet kind of window opened up. Hibernate keeps writing all data access code like 'Hibernate: select table10_.col1 as COL10_, table10_.col2 as COL20_,..."  I was wondering if there is any configuration I can set for Hibernate to write these queries to some kind of log file? Possibly to localhost-log under tomcat/logs?

Comment: I swear this is a third time I see this question asked in so many days. Can we move it, with corresponding answer(s) to FAQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not logging, it's Hibernate's "show_sql". Look for a property named "hibernate.show_sql" being set to "true". Change it to false or just remove it entirely to get rid of those. Then see the [the Configuration chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) in the Hibernate ref for how to set up SQL logging in Hibernate.

Comment: Isn't show_sql a legacy configuration setting? I believe it is mostly used in projects that were initially written in Hibernate pre 3.3 version.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use show_sql. Unfortunately, it's still used in [the tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-configuration) in the reference guide, though.

Comment: @Ryan.. thanks for the reply.. I set the show_sql to false in sessionfactory bean definition and it worked for me.. still have to work on sql logging. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

@Ryan-Stewart  is right but it can be a Pass through Java JDBC driver that can log `SQL` and/or `JDBC calls` for other JDBC drivers.

With hibernate's logging you have logging similar to :

```
 select bs0_.A_REF as A2_7_0_ from B bs0_ where  bs0_.other = 0 and bs0_.A_REF=?  
 TRACE 2011-08-  03 00:30:45,317 binding '123' to parameter: 1
```

Note the '?' instead of the real parameter value.

With Pass through JDBC driver you have logging similar to :

```
select bs0_.A_REF as A2_7_0_ from B bs0_ where  bs0_.other = 0 and bs0_.A_REF=123
```

All the bind parameter are resolved.

[log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) is one of those pass through JDBC driver.